# How to change the colour of a hyperlink in navbar depending what page you are on?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

For this example let's just say a navbar contains the elements:

```
cats - dogs - sheep - cows
```

I want to make it so if you are on the `cats` page, the `cats` text is red but the rest stays white, if you are on the `dogs` page then `dogs` goes blue etc etc?

Comment: assuming the scope of this issue will broaden (beyond hyperlink colors) as you go deeper into development, you should seek guidance about [adaptive navigation](http://www.spartandesign.biz/flexible-design/unit04-adaptive-navigation).

Comment: Don't think I made myself clear..If you have the navbar as follows:

cats - dogs - sheep - cows

if you click on the cats hyperlink, it loads up the cats page, all the content is whatever colour you set, but the cats word hyperlink now turns to red because that's the page you are on. So if you click dogs, all the writing on the dogs page will be whatever colour you have set as default but the dog's hyperlink word will be blue to show you are on that page.

Comment: ok, i get that, only suggested to refer to this issue in a more generic fashion as this could affect the entire app design (and expend your horizons while you're at it).

Answer (score 2):

Create a class (say `.active`) and assign it to the active tag on each page (the cats tag would get the active class on the cats page). Your code would look like this:

**HTML**

```
<a class="active">cats</a>
<a href="dogs.html">dogs</a>
<a href="sheep.html">sheep</a>
<a href="cows.html">cows</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    color: white;
}

a.active {
    color: red;
}
```

**Edit**: If you want every active page to have a different color, you may as well us inline CSS.

```
<a style="color:red">cats</a>
<a href="dogs.html">dogs</a>
<a href="sheep.html">sheep</a>
<a href="cows.html">cows</a>
```

Comment: Don't think I made myself clear..If you have the navbar as follows:

cats - dogs - sheep - cows

if you click on the cats hyperlink, it loads up the cats page, all the content is whatever colour you set, but the cats word hyperlink now turns to red because that's the page you are on. So if you click dogs, all the writing on the dogs page will be whatever colour you have set as default but the dog's hyperlink word will be blue to show you are on that page.

Comment: So you'd have some sort of javascript or something saying if you are on index.php, this fount changes to red, if you are on dogs.php dogs changes to blue?

Comment: Sorry this might be easier to understand..

It's really simple what I want to do... if the user is on index.php then 'latest post's in the navbar turns red, if the user is on ideas.php then 'ideas' in the navbar turns orange, if the user is on facts.php then 'facts' in the navbar turns yellow.

When one of these navbar words changes the colour, the rest still are white.

Comment: Can you provide a visual example of what you are talking about?